# I have the visual basic code on excel and need help resolving this

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Refresh()
'
' Refresh Macro
'
    'Save a copy with date stamp before refreshing data
    Dim dtToday As String
    dtToday = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:="\\NABDC01SDPRS01\C01905_SHARE_S_01\TOR1\Resource\Service Ontario RESP Tracker\Archived\RESP Leads List_" & dtToday & ".xlsm"
'
    Dim reccnt As Integer
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - service_ontario_master_list").Refresh
    
    'Added logic in hope that it will wait for connectino to refresh before running the rest of code
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    Sheets("Working List").Select
    'Unprotect sheet
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    
    'Added logic to remove all filter before delete.  This should resolve the duplicate issue
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Working List").ListObjects("Table2").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    
    Cells.Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    reccnt = Range("A3") + 1
    Range("A5:AO1000").Select
    Selection.clear
    Sheets("Query").Select
    Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(reccnt, 40)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Working List").Select
    Range("A5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("S3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("S5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    
   
    Range(Cells(5, 22), Cells(5 + reccnt, 22)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=Lists!$D$3:$D$6"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    Range(Cells(5, 29), Cells(5 + reccnt, 29)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=Lists!$D$3:$D$6"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    Range(Cells(5, 35), Cells(5 + reccnt, 35)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=Lists!$D$3:$D$6"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    Range("AA5").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=Lists!$B$3:$B$12"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    Range(Cells(5, 27), Cells(5 + reccnt, 27)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=Lists!$B$3:$B$12"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    Range(Cells(5, 33), Cells(5 + reccnt, 33)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=Lists!$B$3:$B$12"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    Range(Cells(5, 39), Cells(5 + reccnt, 39)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=Lists!$B$3:$B$12"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    Range(Cells(5, 3), Cells(5 + reccnt, 3)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=Lists!$K$3:$K$4"
        .IgnoreBlank = False
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    
    'Add data validation (drop down) for Status and Outcome
    Range("T5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=Lists!$N$3:$N$4"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    Range("U5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=Lists!$B$3:$B$5"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    
    'Sort list: lead arrival data aesc and UID aesc
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Working List").ListObjects("Table2").sort.SortFields _
        .clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Working List").ListObjects("Table2").sort.SortFields _
        .Add2 Key:=Range("Table2[Lead Arrival Date]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
        Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Working List").ListObjects("Table2").sort.SortFields _
        .Add2 Key:=Range("Table2[UID]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Working List").ListObjects("Table2").sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    'Hide calculation columns
    Range("A:B").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("F:G").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Range("Y:Y").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    'Freeze Panel
    Range("H5").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    
    'Protect Sheet
    Columns("T:AN").Select
    Selection.Locked = False
    Selection.FormulaHidden = False
    Range("V1:AN4").Select
    Selection.Locked = True
    Selection.FormulaHidden = False
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Locked = False
    Selection.FormulaHidden = False
    Range("C1:C4").Select
    Selection.Locked = True
    Selection.FormulaHidden = False
    Columns("D:U").Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
        AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
    
    'Date Cloumns Adjustment
    Columns("W:W").ColumnWidth = 13
    Columns("W:W").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    Columns("AD:AD").ColumnWidth = 13
    Columns("AD:AD").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    Columns("AJ:AJ").ColumnWidth = 13
    Columns("AJ:AJ").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    
    Range("V4").Select
    
End Sub
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: **1)** We could use a little more detail than that. **2)** where did that error occur? **3)** Please review how to create a [**Minimal, reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Also something to seriously consider: [**VBA - Avoid Using Select**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: "need help resolving this" - what *exactly* is the "this" you need help with?

Comment: This looks like it is mostly generated by the macro-recorder. That really isn't a good tool for any nontrivial VBA programming.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.